# CSS table layout: why does table-row not accept a margin?

Tags: html, css

```css
.container {
  width: 850px;
  padding: 0;
  display: table;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
.row {
  display: table-row;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  /* HERE */
}
.home_1 {
  width: 64px;
  height: 64px;
  padding-right: 20px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  display: table-cell;
}
.home_2 {
  width: 350px;
  height: 64px;
  padding: 0px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  font-size: 150%;
  display: table-cell;
}
.home_3 {
  width: 64px;
  height: 64px;
  padding-right: 20px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  display: table-cell;
}
.home_4 {
  width: 350px;
  height: 64px;
  padding: 0px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  font-size: 150%;
  display: table-cell;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="home_1"></div>
    <div class="home_2"></div>
    <div class="home_3"></div>
    <div class="home_4"></div>
  </div>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="home_1"></div>
    <div class="home_2"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

My question is relative to the line marked `HERE` in the CSS. I found out that the rows are too near to each other, so I tried to add a bottom margin to separate them. Unfortunately it does not work. I have to add the margins to the table cells to separate the rows.

What is the reason behind this behavior?

Also, is it ok to use this strategy to perform layouting as I am doing:

```
[icon] - text      [icon] - text
[icon] - text      [icon] - text
```

or is there a better strategy?

Comment: If you want space between the rows, add padding-bottom to home_4.

Comment: @SatbirKira That's the answer

Answer (score 92, accepted):

See the CSS 2.1 standard, section 17.5.3. When you use `display:table-row`, the height of the DIV is solely determined by the height of the `table-cell` elements in it. Thus, margin, padding, and height on those elements have no effect.

http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/tables.html

Comment: but adding margin-top the the table-cell doesn't work either

Answer (score 39):

How's this for a work around (using an actual table)?

```css
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
}

tr.row {
    border-bottom: solid white 30px; /* change "white" to your background color */
}
```

It's not as dynamic, since you have to explicitly set the color of the border (unless there's a way around that too), but this is something I'm experimenting with on a project of my own.

**Edit** to include comments regarding `transparent`:

```css
tr.row {
    border-bottom: 30px solid transparent;
}
```

Comment: Try 'transparent' instead of 'white' as the color.

Comment: It works perfectly for me, even without table collapse, just to add transparent border to table-cells ! thanks !

Comment: No good if you want borders.

Answer (score 18):

The closest thing I've seen would be to set `border-spacing: 0 30px;` to the container div. However, this just leaves me with space on the upper edge of the table, which defeats the purpose, since you wanted margin-bottom.

Comment: also, you can try `line-height`

Comment: You can remove spaces on top and bottom with `margin: -30px 0`.

Comment: Out of all these workarounds, border-spacing seems like the most semantic option. Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

Have you tried setting the bottom margin to `.row div`, i.e. to your "cells"? 
When you work with actual HTML tables, you cannot set margins to rows, too - only to cells.

Comment: Unfortunately, that didn't work. Only "padding" can affect the div with `display: table`. However, that's not quite the same as margin...

Answer (score 5):

There is a pretty simple fix for this, the `border-spacing` and `border-collapse` CSS attributes work on `display: table`.

You can use the following to get padding/margins in your cells.

```css
.container {
  width: 850px;
  padding: 0;
  display: table;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  border-collapse: separate;
  border-spacing: 15px;
}

.row {
  display: table-row;
}

.home_1 {
  width: 64px;
  height: 64px;
  padding-right: 20px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  display: table-cell;
}

.home_2 {
  width: 350px;
  height: 64px;
  padding: 0px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  font-size: 150%;
  display: table-cell;
}

.home_3 {
  width: 64px;
  height: 64px;
  padding-right: 20px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  display: table-cell;
}

.home_4 {
  width: 350px;
  height: 64px;
  padding: 0px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  font-size: 150%;
  display: table-cell;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="home_1">Foo</div>
    <div class="home_2">Foo</div>
    <div class="home_3">Foo</div>
    <div class="home_4">Foo</div>
  </div>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="home_1">Foo</div>
    <div class="home_2">Foo</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Note that you *have* to have

```css
border-collapse: separate;
```

Otherwise it will not work.

Comment: This works like a charm, but the only problem is, as soon as i apply border-separate it removes the border from the row, i had used border on the row as border-bottom:1px solid #000, any idea?

Comment: This is the genuine and the cleanest solution. Must be upvoted much more. Thanks Kris.

Answer (score 0):

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5q5f6Lsy/)

```
 .row-seperator{
   border-top: solid transparent 50px;
 }

<table>
   <tr><td>Section 1</td></tr>
   <tr><td>row1 1</td></tr>
   <tr><td>row1 2</td></tr>
   <tr>
      <td class="row-seperator">Section 2</td>
   </tr>
   <tr><td>row2 1</td></tr>
   <tr><td>row2 2</td></tr>
</table>


#Outline
Section 1
row1 1
row1 2


Section 2
row2 1
row2 2
```

this can be another solution

Answer (score 0):

Add spacer span between two elements, then make it unvisible:

```
<img src="#" />
<span class="spacer">---</span>
<span>Text TEXT</span>

.spacer {
    visibility: hidden
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Works - Add Spacing To Table**

```
#options table {
  border-spacing: 8px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want a specific margin e.g. 20px, you can put the table inside a div.

```
<div id="tableDiv">
    <table>
      <tr>
        <th> test heading </th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td> test data </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

So the #tableDiv has a margin of 20px but the table itself has a width of 100%, forcing the table to be the full width except for the margin on either sides.

```
#tableDiv {
  margin: 20px;
}

table {
  width: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

adding a br tag between the divs worked. add br tag between two divs that are display:table-row in a parent with display:table