# Spacing between rows

Tags: html, css

I have divs that are set to specific displays to mimic a table. So basically I want to achieve the style that is shown in the image when a row is selected. I have tried padding and margins but it doesn't seem to work. Anyone has any idea how I can do this?

[image]

```css
.table {
  display: table;
}
.header {
  display: table-header-group;
  font-weight: bold;
}
.row {
  display: table-row-group;
}
.cell {
  display: table-cell;
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 5px;
}
.selected {
  background: red;
  margin: 20px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  border-radius: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="table">
  <div class="header">
    <div class="cell">Header 1</div>
    <div class="cell">Header 2</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row selected">
    <div class="cell">Row 1 Cell 1</div>
    <div class="cell">Row 1 Cell 2</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="cell">Row 2 Cell 1</div>
    <div class="cell">Row 2 Cell 2</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="cell">Row 3 Cell 1</div>
    <div class="cell">Row 3 Cell 2</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Where is the code that you've tried?

Comment: What do you mean by "when a row is selected"? Can you show us your HTML/CSS code?

Comment: Alternatively using `table` instead `div`? No :(

Comment: Are you still searching for an answer to your question? If so, can you advise what you're missing?

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
$('.row').on('click', function () {
    $('.table div').removeClass('selected');
    $(this).addClass('selected');
});
```

Fiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/dzbx8dkt/

Edit:  Realized you focus here is about the CSS styling, not the functionality.  Right?  Maybe the best option is a div absolutely positioned on the selected row.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this can help you:

```css
.table {
    display: table;
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-bottom: 0;
}

.row {
    display: table-row-group;
}

.header .{
    display: table-header-group;
    font-weight: bold;
    
}

.cell {
    display: table-cell;
    padding: 5px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
  
}

.cell:first-child{
  border-right: 1px solid black;
}


.selected + .row .cell{
  border-top: 1px solid black;
}

.selected .cell{
    background: red;
 
}

.selected .cell:first-child{
  border-right: 0;
  border-radius: 10px 0 0 10px;
  border-bottom: 0px;
  
}

.selected .cell:nth-child(2){
  border-radius: 0 10px 10px 0;
  border-bottom: 0px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  
<div class="table">
<div class="row header">
    <div class="cell">Header 1</div>
    <div class="cell">Header 2</div>
</div>
<div class="row selected">
    <div class="cell">Row 1 Cell 1</div>
    <div class="cell">Row 1 Cell 2</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="cell">Row 2 Cell 1</div>
    <div class="cell">Row 2 Cell 2</div>
</div>
<div class="row footer">
    <div class="cell">Row 3 Cell 1</div>
    <div class="cell">Row 3 Cell 2</div>
</div>
  
</body>
</html>
```

The only problem is the padding property are not applicable to display: table-row-group, table-header-group, table-footer-group, table-row, table-column-group and table-column elements.

Reference:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/padding

Example:
http://jsbin.com/tofokoriri/edit?html,css,output

Comment: Nice :) but, missing padding or margin... margin property is not applicable to `display: table-cell` elements and `padding` property doesn't create space between edges of the cells. :(  refer link : http://stackoverflow.com/a/1993307/3279496

Answer (score 0):

Not a real answer but maybe it will give you some hint
You can play a bit with the [outline](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/outline) property.

```css
.table {
  display: table;
}
.header {
  display: table-header-group;
  font-weight: bold;
}
.row {
  display: table-row-group;
}
.cell {
  display: table-cell;
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 5px;
}
.selected {
  background: red;
  margin: 20px;
  border-radius: 10px;
}
.selected { outline: 2px solid blue;}
.selected .cell:first-child {border-right:1px solid red;}
.selected .cell:last-child {border-left:1px solid red;}
```

```html
<div class="table">
  <div class="header">
    <div class="cell">Header 1</div>
    <div class="cell">Header 2</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row selected">
    <div class="cell">Row 1 Cell 1</div>
    <div class="cell">Row 1 Cell 2</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="cell">Row 2 Cell 1</div>
    <div class="cell">Row 2 Cell 2</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="cell">Row 3 Cell 1</div>
    <div class="cell">Row 3 Cell 2</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

something like this? I added another `div` layer to create that padding effect that was desired, I hope that this solution fits your needs.

```js
$('.row').on('click', function () {    
    $('.table div').removeClass('selected');
    $(this).addClass('selected');
});
```

```css
.table {
    display: table;
}
.header {
    display: table-header-group;
    font-weight: bold;
}
.row {
    display: table-row-group;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.cell {
    display: table-cell;
    border: 1px solid black;
    padding: 10px;
}
.selected .cell {
    padding: 10px;
}
.selected .cell .content{
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
}
.selected .cell:nth-child(1) .content{
    background-color: red;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
    border-top-left-radius: 10px;
    padding-left: 5px;
    margin-left: -5px;
    margin-right: -11px;
    
}
.selected .cell:nth-child(2) .content{
    background-color: red;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
    border-top-right-radius: 10px;
    padding-right: 5px;
    margin-right: -5px;
    padding-left: 11px;
    margin-left: -11px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="table">
    <div class="header">
        <div class="cell">Header 1</div>
        <div class="cell">Header 2</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="cell"><div class="content">Row 1 Cell 1</div></div>
        <div class="cell"><div class="content">Row 1 Cell 2</div></div>
    </div>
    <div class="row selected">
        <div class="cell"><div class="content">Row 2 Cell 1</div></div>
        <div class="cell"><div class="content">Row 2 Cell 2</div></div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="cell"><div class="content">Row 3 Cell 1</div></div>
        <div class="cell"><div class="content">Row 3 Cell 2</div></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you have not problem with toggling class `selected` with jQuery, so if you have to stick with that markup and `display: table`, here is my solution:

```
.table {
        display: table;
        border: 1px solid black;
    }

    .header {
        display: table-header-group;
        font-weight: bold;
    }

    .row {
        display: table-row-group;
    }

    .cell {
        display: table-cell;
        padding: 5px;
        border-bottom: 1px solid black;
    }

    .cell:first-child{
        border-right: 1px solid #000;
    }

    .row:last-child > .cell {
        border-bottom: none;
        border-top: 1px solid black;
    }

    .selected {}

    .selected > div:first-child {
        background: red;
        border-radius: 10px 0 0 10px;
        border: 4px solid white;
        border-right: none;
    }

    .selected > div:last-child {
        background: red;
        border-radius: 0 10px 10px 0;
        border: 4px solid white;
        border-left: none;
    }
```